# I imported libsodium.js and my build got very large suddenly, but selective imports aren't an option. What else can I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I just added a library called libsodium.js to handle certain crypto functionality I need to support. The problem is that it increased my build size tremendously. I'd really like to cut out the parts I'm not using, but the library doesn't seem to support selective imports. I filed a ticket with the code manager, but I don't know when or if that'll be addressed. In the meantime, what can I do to reduce the size of my webpack build as it's presently over 1MB in size.

Repo is here: https://github.com/ava-labs/slopes

[image]

Thanks!